# ngFor Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token = at column

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing an Angular app, built with Angular CLI. I have a model called `globalModel` in my component. This model will be built using the user inputs in the previous page. In this current page, I am displaying the data contained in this model to the user in a HTML table. Here's how i do it:

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="criteria1" name="parameter1Identifier">Class A
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="criteria1" name="parameter1Identifier">Class B
.
.

<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="criteria2" name="parameter2Identifier">Type 1
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="criteria2" name="parameter2Identifier">Type 2
.
.

<table>
<thead>
  <tr *ngIf="tableColumnCount">
    <th *ngFor="let colNumber of tableColumnCount | rangePipe">
      <input type="checkbox"
             [checked]=false
             (click)="selectAllElementsInColumnOfTheTableIn(colNumber);">
      select column {{ n + 1 }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of globalModel | modelToArrayOfArraysFilter: criteria1: criteria2;">  
     <td *ngFor="let acol of row; let i = index; totalColumnsOfTheTable = row.length">      <--- Error!
         ....
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the `totalColumnsOfTheTable` is defined in the component as follows:

```
set totalColumnsOfTheTable(count: number) {
    if ( this.tableColumnCount < count ) {
      this.tableColumnCount = count;
      this._cd.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

The `row` of this table can have any number of elements like [obj], [obj1, obj2], [objA, objB, objC], [objN], ... This data is filtered from the model based on the `criteria1` and `criteria2` which the user selects on the radio button. So based on this, the table data gets populated. The variable `tableColumnCount` will have the count of the total number of columns and the table should update accordingly.  To determine the total column count I am trying to use the setter in `*ngFor` as `totalColumnsOfTheTable = row.length`.

But, Angular throws error like

> "Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token = at column 65
>   in [let acol of row; let i = index; totalColumnsOfTheTable =
>   index] ".

I tried using the `trackBy` to acheve the same. I figured out that the `this` doesn't refer to 'component'. So, if i call `this.totalColumnsOfTheTable = index` doesn't work!
Please help me to determine the total column count or any other way to set the component variables within `*ngFor` loop. Any help is greatly appreciated. Any suggestions to the approach is most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `let` in front of your new variable, it should be like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let acol of row; let i = index; let totalColumnsOfTheTable = row.length">...</td>
```

Comment: if i add let, it becomes a local variable of the template. But, i want it in the component. That's the reason why i haven't added `let`.   Is there a way i can store the `index` value in the `public totalColumnsOfTheTable : number;` variable of the component?

Comment: Ah I see sorry, do you know where your variable globalModel will be updated? Maybe you can use a "set globalModel" with a loop in it to count the length of each items in it?

Comment: If understand right, the variable is updated when you click on the radio button, you can maybe add a (change) on each of your <input> with this function counting the length of each row.

Comment: Or, another way to do this would be to use a function tableColumnCount() instead of a variable. Then you could put your loop through globalModel to find the longest row inside of this function and the function will update itself each time globalModel is updated.