# TypeError Function expected: App with Angular, TypeScript, Firebase and Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've researched errors which come up with "TypeError Function expect" such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862033/ngfor-template-parse-errors-parser-error-unexpected-token-at-column) and [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/800) but they don't seem to be relevant to this problem and I can't figure out how to solve it. I've been at it for 6+ hours.

Please can someone help me?

I'm a newbie and making a shopping list app using Angular, Firebase, Ionic 3 and TypeScript. It essentially should add new items to the display screen/view of the app i.e. HomePage.

The below is the interface code:

```
export interface Item {
    key?: string;
    name: string;
    quantity: number;
    price: number;

}
```

The below is the code for the HomePage.ts, where the interface Item is imported:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ShoppingListService } from '../../services/shopping list/shopping-list.service';
import { Item } from '../../models/item/item.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private shopping: ShoppingListService) {
  this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping
  .getShoppingList() // database list
  .snapshotChanges() // gets key and value
  .map(changes => { // for each change, get a new object
    return changes.map(c => ({
      key: c.payload.key,
      ...c.payload.val()
    }));
  });
  }
```

The below is the homepage.html where the list of items should display:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingList$ | async" >
    {{item.name}}
   </ion-item>
```

This is the service provider code shopping-list.service.ts which connects to the firebase database:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Item } from '../../models/item/item.model';

@Injectable()
export class ShoppingListService {
    private shoppingListRef= this.db.list<Item>('shopping-list');

    constructor (private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
    getShoppingList(){
        return this.shoppingListRef;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Function expected
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:74479:9)
   at SwitchMapSubscriber.prototype._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:62604:13)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:13)
   at Subscriber.prototype._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:13)
   at Subject.prototype.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23237:17)
   at Subscriber.prototype._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:13)
   at Notification.prototype.observe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52062:17)
   at DelaySubscriber.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:76789:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

First, import this:

```
import {of} from "rxjs";
```

After, replace this:

```
 this.shoppingList$ = of(this.shopping
  .getShoppingList() // database list
  .snapshotChanges() // gets key and value
  .map(changes => { // for each change, get a new object
    return changes.map(c => ({
      key: c.payload.key,
      ...c.payload.val()
    }));
  }));
```

And rename the type in your service:

```
private shoppingListRef= this.db.list<Item[]>('shopping-list');
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I appreciate your effort. I tried it and it comes up with a new error: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ key: string; name: string; quantity: number; price: number; }[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<{ key: string; name: string; quantity: number; price: number; }[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': length, pop, push, join, and 17 more.

Comment: your variable return a Item instead a array of Item, i'l edit the post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that gave the same errors: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ length: number; toString():. 25 more ...; key: string; }[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': length, pop, push, join, and 17 more....

Comment: It also added the following error to the service functions: "Argument of type 'Item' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item[]'.
  Type 'Item' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more."